# How to run PHP code only once on node creation?

Tags: entities

I'm using Drupal 7, and the [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module.
I want to run code just once, when the node is created.

Is there any specific function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to run code just once when a node is created, the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module may be a better choice.

Using Rules, you can do the following:

1. Create a new rule that acts on the event "After saving new content."
2. As the action, "Set a data value" and target the field you want to modify (this would be a standard field rather than a computed field in this case).
3. As the "Value", input your PHP code in php tags.

This way the code will be evaluated only once.

Comment: This is a case where I would use the Rules module. Using the Computed Field module, the code should verify the node is being created, and that code would run every time the node is edited; with the Rules module, the code would be executed only when a node is created.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [hook_node_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7)

For how to use it have a look at [book_node_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21book%21book.module/function/book_node_insert/7), but you can access any field you want: $node->title contains the title and for fields it's something like $node->field_myfield[0]['value'] (a text field called myfield).

The easy way is to install [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and add dpm($node) inside your function.